# Change color of passepartout or outside the render region

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, color

I have some issue, may be you can help me with. In the past (blender 2.7 or so) it was possible to change the color of the outside space of the render region....I needed it, so the edges of the  picture fitted to the background of a webpage where I wanted to put the image into. ...the color could be changed at preferences->themes

now it seems that there is only the passpartout, but the color can't be changed from black to another color. Do you have an idea how to fix that problem (within the 3D viewport)? Would be great if you know how to change that (is there a add on may be, which brings back that "function"?
best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

The color for Passepartout of the render region (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) can be changed at *Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Theme Space > Gradient Colors*